# HTTP header and message body separator clarification

Tags: http, http-headers

I'm going to be parsing metadata that will have the same format that HTTP headers/messages do.

I was reading [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html) and I'm trying to understand this more clearly.

Is each HTTP header separated by CRLF (\r\n) and then the separator between the headers and the message body CRLFCRLF(\r\n\r\n)? I couldn't find (or maybe I missed it) anything that detailed what the standard was.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2) (which you shouldn't look at anymore, [7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3) is its successor) states:

> ```
> generic-message = start-line
>                   *(message-header CRLF)
>                   CRLF
>                   [ message-body ]
> ```

So there's:

1. The start-line, which is either a `Request-Line` or a `Status-Line`, both of which end in CRLF.
2. Zero or more message-headers, each ending in CRLF.
3. A CRLF to denote the end of the start-line and headers.
4. Optionally, a message body.

That being said, you don't want to parse HTTP yourself. Use a library for that.

Example
[image]
*(picture [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages))*

Comment: Thanks for the response - didn't know about 7230. This metadata isn't HTTP but we were going to be using the HTTP standard for separation ... do you have a library you recommend for parsing that stuff? We're using Java as the language.

Comment: @josh no, I can't recommend any I'm afraid.

Comment: I have added a picture, if you don't like it, feel free to roll it back, thanks for the great documented answer.

Answer (score 0):

at the start of a message there is a request/status line.
other then that:
according to RFC2616, you are absolutely correct,
however, while RFC2616 specifies the headers' format as *(message-header CRLF) 
RFC7230 specifies it as *( header-field CRLF )
apart from the name change, it doesn't seem to be any different, the format for the headers is the same.

tldr; yes.

p.s. parsing the headers for an http message is not that hard, took me a few hours, parsing the message body is mildly difficult but honestly, you should try doing it, it's a good challenge.