# HTTP header cut in half with `urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError: [MissingHeaderBodySeparatorDefect()], unparsed data`

Tags: python, nginx, python-requests, python-3.8, urllib3

I spotted a weird warning in logs:

```
[WARNING] urllib3.connectionpool:467: Failed to parse headers (url=https://REDACTED): [MissingHeaderBodySeparatorDefect()], unparsed data: 'trol,Content-Type\r\n\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 465, in _make_request
assert_header_parsing(httplib_response.msg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/util/response.py", line 91, in assert_header_parsing
raise HeaderParsingError(defects=defects, unparsed_data=unparsed_data)
urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError: [MissingHeaderBodySeparatorDefect()], unparsed data: 'trol,Content-Type\r\n\r\n'
```

This is from calling a standard `requests.post()` on a web service I fully control (a Python app behind nginx).

When I turn on `debuglevel=1` in `http.client.HTTPResponse` I see this:

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
header: Date: Tue, 30 Nov 2021 22:14:04 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Vary: Accept-Encoding
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
header: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
header: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
header: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Con
```

Note the last header ending abruptly in `,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Con`.

Clearly, `requests==2.26.0` (via `urllib3==1.26.7` via `http.client`) cuts the last header in half for some reason during parsing, and then later complains it has "left over" data with the remaining `trol,Content-Type\r\n\r\n`.

In this case the warning is not critical, because the header is not really needed. But it's scary this is happening, because… what else is being cut / misparsed?

The same endpoint works fine from e.g. `curl`:

```sh
$ curl -i -XPOST https://REDACTED
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 04 Dec 2021 20:08:59 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 53
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Con
trol,Content-Type

…JSON response…
```

Any idea what could be wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That `curl` output doesn't look too good to me. It's got the same split in the header that your Python `requests` code chokes on.  Perhaps `curl` doesn't given an error because it doesn't try to parse these things?  Anyway, I've never seen `requests` generate the error you are getting, and combined with your `curl` output I can only conclude that your problem is with your server-side code.  Your server code is emitting those broken headers. You have chosen not to share any of your server-side code with us, and until you do it will be difficult for us to help you any further.

Comment: Check this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131727/http-header-and-message-body-separator-clarification) Hope it will be useful

Comment: Read about it in your favorite programming book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your webserver, or its configuration, looks broken. Have a look at what is generating that CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header because it is not permitted to contain a line break.

Comment: Thanks Andy – that's all the clue I needed! The issue was indeed with the nginx proxy config which contained this extra unwanted line break (masquerading as word wrap). A one-character fix in the end.